# How to provide a path to a folder in Jenkins pipeline job build

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline job in Jenkins. The job will call a batch file and once the batch script is run successfully , some items are saved in a specified location.

For example :
Job ran successfully
Build passed
In D:/temp folder some files are saved after the build.

I want to print this location D:/temp in the build
Once the job link is opened ,the page should provide a link to that folder

Expected result:
If I open a job like below
http:///job//<build_number>/
The page view
Build #<build_number>
**Build Artifacts (link to the folder D:/temp)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something needs to be accessed from Jekins webpage then you must Archive it. Archived files will be accessible from the Jenkins webpage. To do this job `Archive Artifacts` is used.
Please see below example:

```
dir("D:\\temp")
{
  // If you want to show all files that are present in temp directory:
  archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true, artifacts: "/"
}
```

Comment: Do we need any additional plugin for this zipping process

Comment: @ViBe you can do that using ``tar`` command and then archive it. ``tar -cvzf output3.tar.gz  D:\\temp\\*``

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [archiveArtifats](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/#archiveartifacts-archive-the-artifacts) and [copyArtifacts](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact/) ?

D:\Temp is local to your agent. ArchiveAtrifacts is stored on the controller, with the job config and logs, accessible from anywhere.